# System will not boot after making changes in BIOS

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, bios

i am having this weird problem now. Actually i am trying to install windows 7 in my system through usb. So, i change the boot priorities accordingly and save the changes and exit. After the computer starts again it just stays in the black screen and nothing happens.

I recently changed my motherboards battery too. Also, in order to be sure that there is nothing wrong with the OS in the usb. I completely powered off my PC waited for a while and again started it.

This time, i changed the time and date of system in bios, saved it and exited the bios. the problem still permits. it wont boot at all. Tried a lot of things but nothing seems to be helpful.

[Asus M2N68AM Plus](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M2N68AM_PLUS/HelpDesk/) motherboard

Comment: Make and model of PC?

Comment: How did you create your bootable USB drive? Did you select to disable Secure Boot in your bios? Have you activated the Legacy boot mode? "Change boot priorities" is too vague so we can help.

Comment: @Moab My pc is pretty old.
Motherboard- Asus m2n68 am plus
Ram - 4gb
HDD: 1TB
processor: AMD ATHLON X2

Comment: @Natsu Kage: I do not know how to activate legacy boot mode because i do not see any such option in bios. I created my usb bootable through rufus. For your reference my motherboard is Asus M2N68 AM PLUS.

Comment: No need to change boot priorities, revert the changes you made, then use F8 or Esc key at the asus logo screen to get a one time boot menu, select your usb boot device, this make no changes to boot priority, which is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

This particular BIOS needs you to manually select the USB drive as the first bootable option:

> After going into the BIOS, select "Boot" from the top of the screen.
>
> Next, select "Hard Disk Drives" and highlight the USB Device and press
>   the + key till it is at the top.
>
> Next, press ESC to go back to the "Boot" screen and select "Boot
>   Device Priority".
>
> Again, highlight the USB Device and press the + key till it is at the
>   top of the list.

You can also try ESC, F8, F12, etc for a boot option? Weirdly, can't find the exact key in the manual. It should be ESC.